# Storing values in an array and passing to another html file - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a $.ajax() which is calculating the time for reading a file for the given number of iterations. I have two things to be taken care off.

1) I am finding difficulty in storing calculated time for every iterations in an array, I need to store all the values. // In the below code, value of "elapsed" variable needs to be stored in array

2) All stored array values have to be passed to another function which is present in some other html file.

Can anyone help me in this?

```
 // used to inform the number of times ajax should read the given file ( I mean to calculate time )
   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                 doAjax();
            }, (i * 500));
        })(i);
   }


   function doAjax() {


       $.ajax({
           url: "SHI.mp4", //file which needs to be read
           beforeSend: function (xhr) {
               xhr.start = new Date().getTime();
           },
           success: function (res, status, xhr) {
               var end = new Date().getTime();
               var elapsed = end - xhr.start; // time taken to read the file
                }
       });



   }
```

Comment: what do you mean `in another html file`. Why are you using AJAX on `.mp4` file?

Comment: Another html file means - I want those stored array values to be used in other function which is present in another file.                      
I am using AJAX to read files stored in server.